# Merge list with map in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-acm

I am writing terraform script to automate the provision of acm for domains, the issue that I am facing is how can I merge the domain and subject_alternative_names like it should pick first domain from domain_name and merge it with first block in subject_alternative_name and go on.

Variable.tf

```
variable "domain_name" {
  description = "Configuration for alb settings"
  default = [
    "domain.com",
    "helloworld.com",
    "helloworld2.com",
  ]
}
variable "subject_alternative_names" {
  description = "subject_alternative_names"
  default = [ {
    domain.com = {
    "domain.com",
    "domain2.com",
    "domain3.com",
    },
    helloworld.com = {
    "helloworld1.com",
    "helloworld2.com"
    },
    hiworld.com = {
    "hiworld1.com",
    "hiworld2.com"
    }
  }]
}
variable "region" {
  description = "name of the region"
  default     = "us-east-1"
}
variable "validation_method" {
  description = "name of the region"
  default     = "DNS"
}
variable "tags" {
  description = "name of the region"
  default     = "Test"
}
```

working variable.tf

```
variable "domain_name" {
  description = "Configuration for alb settings"
  default     = [
    "domain.com",
    "helloworld.com",
    "helloworld2.com",
    "helloworld1.com",
    "helloworld3.com",
  ]
}
variable "subject_alternative_names"{
  description = "subject_alternative_names"
  default     = [
    "domain.com",
    "helloworld.com",
    "helloworld2.com",
    "helloworld1.com",
    "helloworld3.com",
  ]
}
variable "region" {
  description = "name of the region"
  default     = "us-east-1"
}
variable "validation_method" {
  description = "name of the region"
  default     = "DNS"
}
variable "tags" {
  description = "name of the region"
  default     = "Test"
}
```

main.tf

```
module "acm" {
  count                     = length(var.domain_name)
  source                    = "./modules/acm"
  domain_name               = var.domain_name[count.index]
  validation_method         = var.validation_method
  tags                      = var.tags
  subject_alternative_names = var.subject_alternative_names
}
```

resource.tf

```
variable "domain_name" {
  default     = ""
  description = "Nmae of the domain"
}

variable "validation_method" {
  default     = ""
  description = "Validation method DNS or EMAIL"
}

variable "tags" {
  default     = ""
  description = "tags for the ACM certificate"
}

variable "subject_alternative_names" {
  default     = ""
  description = "subject_alternative_names"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "acm_cert" {
  domain_name               = var.domain_name
  validation_method         = var.validation_method
  subject_alternative_names = var.subject_alternative_names
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  tags = {
    Name = var.tags
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `subject_alternative_names` is not a valid TF code. Can you actually provide code that represents your situation?

Comment: I was giving the subject_alternative_names as list and it was working but it was appending the names with all the domain, I was trying that it should pick 1 domain from domain_name and first block from subject_alternative_names then second domain_name and second block from subject_alternative_names

Comment: @Marcin I have added all the code that I have in the question

Comment: This is invalid TF code, it has syntax errors. So the fixing of the syntax errors is your actual issue? Or you have some multiple issues? Also `domain_name` has five items, but has `subject_alternative_names` three items. Why they are different? Why the domains names are different?

Comment: @Marcin I have added the new variable file as workingvariable.tf but I need to convert the subject_alternative_name in maps so that I can merge it with domain. First block with first domain and so on. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a **single map**:

```
variable "domain_name_with_alternate_names" {
  default = {
    "domain.com" = [
      "domain.com",
      "domain2.com",
      "domain3.com",
    ],
    "helloworld.com" = [
      "helloworld1.com",
      "helloworld2.com"
    ],
    "hiworld.com" = [
      "hiworld1.com",
      "hiworld2.com"
    ],
    "hiwodd4.com" = []
  }
}


module "acm" {

  for_each                  = var.domain_name_with_alternate_names
  
  source                    = "./modules/acm"
  domain_name               = each.key
  validation_method         = var.validation_method
  tags                      = var.tags
  subject_alternative_names = each.value
}
```